# Securely store and share a secret with ServiceStack across different logins

Tags: asp.net, security, store, servicestack, private-key

Given is a ServiceStack REST Service that can sign documents with one of the public/private key algorithm. The prvate key is encrypted using a passphrase only the admin of this privat/public key pair knows.

Know it should be possible that other logins then the admin can sign documents (authorized by roles, permissions, etc.)

Currently they need to provide the passphrase for the private key in every signature request as the service needs to decrypt the private key and sign the document.

But i dont want to give the private key passphrase to other users and i also don't like to send it on every request over the wire.

So what is the best way to store the passphrase on the service side so that authorized logins can sign documents without knowing and sending the passphrase.

Is there a possibility to store it (automatically encrypted/decrypted from ServiceStack) in the user's session/UserAuth object?

Or is there are any other solution? It should work on .net and mono.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you look at Microsoft's guidance on encrypting/decrypting config sections. This way you can store it encrypted in web.config and your back end service can have access to it.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx